# What is difference between these two Codes

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I've just solved a hacker rank question. The question is:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/kangaroo/problem

The below solution has passed all 30 tests

```
function kangaroo(x1, v1, x2, v2) {
    var returnVal = "NO";
    if (x2 > x1 && v2 > v1) {
        returnVal = "NO";
    } else if ((x1 - x2) % (v2 - v1) === 0) {
        returnVal = "YES";
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```

But after I've changed the code like as below it hasn't passed 2 tests.

```
function kangaroo(x1, v1, x2, v2) {
    var returnVal = "NO";
    if ((x1 - x2) % (v2 - v1) === 0) {
        returnVal = "YES";
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```

The default value of the returnVal is "NO". So, I think that first if statement shouldn't be necessary. So, why the second code hasn't passed two tests?

Comment: *else* if... ...

Comment: hint: `(x1 - x2) % (v2 - v1) === 0` could be true even if x2 < x1 and v2 < v1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine

```
kangoroo(1,1,2,2)
```

So the first code would return *No* while the second does return *Yes*. You may implement the first condition into the second:

```
function kangaroo(x1, v1, x2, v2){
  if ((x1 - x2) % (v2 - v1) === 0 && !(x2 > x1 && v2 > v1)) {
    return "YES";
  }
 return " No";
}
```

Comment: Ok mate my brain is burnt. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The second condition in the first block of code is an **else** if. It will only run if the first if condition doesn't pass.

You can have input which matches both the if condition and the else if condition. That would result in the output being NO in the first case (the `if` matches and the `else if` is never run) but YES in your modified code (the former `else if` matches).

Answer (score 0):

Try this(written in Java)

x1: initial location of kangaroo 1
& x2: initial location of kangaroo 2

If it is given that x2 > x1

```
static String kangaroo(int x1, int v1, int x2, int v2) {

    int i;
    for(i=0; x1<x2; i++){
        x1 = x1 + v1;
        x2 = x2 + v2;
        if(x1 == x2){
            return "YES";
        } 
    }   
    return "NO";
}
```

Below solution covers all the possibilities like, x1 > x2 or x1 == x2 or x1 < x2.

```
static String kangaroo(int x1, int v1, int x2, int v2) {

    int i, flag = 0;

    if(x1 > x2){
        for(i=0; x1>x2; i++){
            x1 = x1 + v1;
            x2 = x2 + v2;
            if(x1 == x2){
                return "YES";
            }
        }
    }else if(x1 < x2){
        for(i=0; x1<x2; i++){
            x1 = x1 + v1;
            x2 = x2 + v2;
            if(x1 == x2){
                return "YES";
            } 
        }   
    }else
        return "YES";

    return "NO";
}
```

Comment: The question is about Javascript, not Java.

Answer (score 0):

The Simplest Solution is

```
if (v1 <= v2 && x2 > x1) {
    return "NO";
} else {
    return (x2 - x1) % (v2 - v1) == 0 ? "YES" : "NO";
}
```